# How to run selenium server in bash

Tags: linux, selenium, ubuntu-14.04, selenium-chromedriver, selenium-ide

So I've been reading this article about running selenium-ide recorded tests in chrome on windows(http://www.software-testing-tutorials-automation.com/2016/08/run-selenium-ide-test-in-google-chrome.html). I'm using Ubuntu though, and I use newer selenium server version. How should I modify this command for it to work on linux:

```
java -jar selenium-server-standalone-2.46.0.jar -Dwebdriver.chrome.driver=chromedriver.exe
```

I know that i have to delete ".exe" but i get an error like this:

```
Exception in thread "main" com.beust.jcommander.ParameterException: Unknown option: -Dwebdriver.chrome.driver=chromedriver
    at com.beust.jcommander.JCommander.parseValues(JCommander.java:742)
    at com.beust.jcommander.JCommander.parse(JCommander.java:282)
    at com.beust.jcommander.JCommander.parse(JCommander.java:265)
    at com.beust.jcommander.JCommander.<init>(JCommander.java:210)
    at org.openqa.grid.selenium.GridLauncherV3$1.setConfiguration(GridLauncherV3.java:227)
    at org.openqa.grid.selenium.GridLauncherV3.buildLauncher(GridLauncherV3.java:155)
    at org.openqa.grid.selenium.GridLauncherV3.main(GridLauncherV3.java:75)
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `-Dwebdriver…` parameter needs to be passed to `java`, not Selenium itself. So just switching the argument order should work for you:

```
java -Dwebdriver.chrome.driver=chromedriver.exe -jar selenium-server-standalone-2.46.0.jar
```

Relevant Github issues: [1](https://github.com/SeleniumHQ/selenium/issues/2571), [2](https://github.com/SeleniumHQ/selenium/issues/2566)